# Inequalities/numerical values+conditional statements for python?

Tags: python, logic, conditional-statements

I want to make a conditional test for python to check that the value of a given inputted number is equal to or less than 9, and greater than or equal to 0.

```
number =input( "Please enter a number! :" )
Please enter a number! :23
>>> edited_number=float(number)
>>> if edited_number >0 <9:
    print ("Entered value greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 9!")
```

I get a printed message saying:

**entered value greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 9!**

Which obviously is wrong, because the entered value is 23. That then suggests to me that the <9 condition has been ignored for some reason.

Is there some way for me to have a numerical range with a single if? Or will only a single condition be interpreted per if statement?

PS: I am using Python 3.6.0b if that is of any relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"`if edited_number > 0 < 9`"

This doesn't work in python.
You need to specify the variable twice like this:

`if edited_number > 0 and edited_number < 9`

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
if not (0 <= edited_number <= 9):
   print ("Entered value greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 9!")
```

Answer (score 1):

That chained expression isn't doing what you think it does. What you want is:

```
0 <= edited_number <= 9
```

Or if you're not comfortable with chained conditionals you can use the verbose form:

```
0 <= edited_number and edited_number <= 9
```

The expression:

```
edited_number > 0 < 9
```

Is the same as

```
edited_number > 0 and 0 < 9
```

Which evaluates to `True` when `edited_number` is 23.

---

Reference:

[Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

Comment: Isn't your suggested expression the *opposite* of what is desired?

Comment: @ScottHunter Good eye on the typo

Comment: @Moses Koledoyle; can I clarify with you, are you saying my grammar was wrong, rather than the coding? :)

Comment: @apronedsamurai I'll say the conditional expression was not properly written - your coding. The variable should be in the middle. If you're not comfortable with chained conditionals, better to use the verbose form.

Answer (score 0):

```
number =input( "Please enter a number! :" )

edited_number=float(number)
if  not (0 <= edited_number <= 9):
    print ("Entered value greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 9!")
```

input : `23`

output: `Entered value greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 9!`